# Docker on windows wsl not running daemon

Tags: docker, installation, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-machine, docker-daemon

I few days ago I installed docker in my WSL version 2 on windows. On Ubuntu

[image]

I used the following script provided by this page:

https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/install-docker-in-wsl-2-without-docker-desktop

curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com -o get-docker.sh

The problem is that after installing it, docker seems to be ok, but the docker daemon is not working

[image]

As you can see I start the service but if then I check the status it says is not running and also when trying to execute a docker compose or something like that also show the error that the docker daemon is not running

What should I check? I have used docker desktop always but I can not use it now so I have to just use docker in WSL

EDIT: My systemd is enable
but I still got an error

[image]
[image]

[image]

I also tried to start it manually with

sudo dockerd

but I got this error also
[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved here
https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/6655

it was an issue of the iptables, i had to use the legacy ones

Answer (score 1):

Configure **systemd** by editing the file  'wsl.conf ':

```
[boot]
systemd=true
```

Restart wsl...

Then:

```
sudo systemctl start docker.service
```

Here more information for **systemd** for **wsl**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/systemd .

Comment: gabilondo1612@MSI:~$ sudo systemctl start docker.service
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down

Comment: Sorry I missed an important step to allow systemd to run. I edited it.

Comment: as you can see my systemd is enable but I still got this error :(

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps to use docker in your WSL2 Distro

1. Check if you have enabled systemd in your WSL2. Open your `/etc/wsl.conf` and add following line:

```
[boot]
systemd=true
```

Restart your WSL2 Distro

```
wsl --shutdown YOUR_DISTRO
wsl -d YOUR_DISTRO
```

2. Install docker
3. enable the docker daemon with systemd

```
sudo systemd start docker
```

4. check the output of journalctl

```
journalctl -u docker.service
```

5. Test your installation with

```
sudo docker run hello-world
```

Comment: shoudl I install docker executing the same script I already have?? and also should first reintalling docker, remove it or something?

Comment: First of all check the following steps without reinstalling. May you can add some information to your question of these steps.

Comment: I have a problem with thatgabilondo1612@MSI:~$ sudo systemd start docker
[sudo] password for gabilondo1612:
Excess arguments.
gabilondo1612@MSI:~$ journalctl -u docker.service
No journal files were found.
-- No entries --